# Help understand a line of code

Tags: code

this is a weird question, but I read the following line of code:

```
Select[Flatten[Module[{x}, x = #;
       Join[x[[1]], #] & /@ x[[2 ;; -1]]] & /@ igraph, 1], 
   Length@# > 1 &];
```

I was wondering if there is way to write this without the symbols or better if in a simpler way. I know that & means function and /@ means Map. But, I am struggling to write the code without these. Any help is appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: I hesitate to post this, but maybe seeing the prefix forms versus the infix forms will actually help. `Select[Flatten[Map[Function[Module[{x}, x = #;
     Map[Function[Join[x[[1]], #]], x[[2 ;; -1]]]]], igraph], 1], 
 Function[Length[#] > 1]]`. But there is almost certainly a better way to rewrite this entire code. If you could explain what you want to achieve,and also what igraph is expected to be, then we could make progress toward better code.

Comment: `But, I am struggling to write the code without these....`. Could you please share the code that you have written?

Comment: First identify the inner-most construct:  Module[{x}, x = #;
       Join[x[[1]], #] & /@ x[[2 ;; -1]]] & /@ igraph.  note x=# which means each item in the array igraph must be itself an array but the Join operator takes arrays so looks like igraph has the form {{{a},{b},{c}},{{d},{e},{f}}} and so forth.  Then analyze the next layer from this layer then the next.  Try igraph = {{{1}, {2}, {3}}, {{4}, {5}, {6}}, {{7}, {8}, {9}}} then Module[{x}, x = #;
   Join[x[[1]], #] & /@ x[[2 ;; -1]]] & /@ igraph

Answer (score 8):

let's use curry

one by one.

```
Flatten[Module[{x}, x = #; Join[x[[1]], #] & /@ x[[2 ;; -1]]] & /@ igraph, 1] // Select[Length@# > 1 &];
```

```
igraph // 
Map[
    Module[{x}, x = #;
    x[[2 ;; -1]] // Map[Join[x[[1]],#]&]
    ]&
] //
Flatten[# , 1]& // 
Select[Length@# > 1 &];
```

now it seems easier to understand.

read it:

1. take an element `igraph`,
2. map a function on it.

   this function is  `Module[{x}, x = #; x[[2 ;; -1]] // Map[Join[x[[1]],#]&] ]&`,
3. `Flatten[# , 1]&` the result,
4. select elements whose length > 1.

Comment: I write a small article to explain this way. https://medium.com/@wuyudi1109/how-to-write-easy-for-reading-code-in-mathematica-72bcdb1a668c

Answer (score 7):

Mathematica's `FullForm` writes an expression without any abbreviations, not even ones you wish it would use:

```
Hold[Select[Flatten[Module[{x}, x = #;
       Join[x[[1]], #] & /@ x[[2 ;; -1]]] & /@ igraph, 1], 
   Length@# > 1 &]] // FullForm
(*
Hold[Select[
  Flatten[
   Map[Function[
     Module[List[x], 
      CompoundExpression[Set[x, Slot[1]], 
       Map[Function[Join[Part[x, 1], Slot[1]]], 
        Part[x, Span[2, -1]]]]]], igraph], 1], 
  Function[Greater[Length[Slot[1]], 1]]]]
*)
```

The `TreeForm[expr]` and `ExpressionTree[expr]` make the nested `[]` easier to read in theory, but the tree quickly gets too large to read.

Here's a way to display the nested structure, in which I took the liberty of abbreviating a few commands:

```
nested // ClearAll;
nested // Attributes = {HoldAll};
myGrid = Grid[#, Alignment -> {Left, Top}, 
    Dividers -> {{{True, {False}}, 1 -> Pink}, False}] &;

(* Optional abbreviations *)
nested[e_Slot] := myGrid@{{HoldForm[e]}}; (* Slot[1]=#1, Slot[2]=#2... *)
nested[e_Part] := myGrid@{{HoldForm[e]}}; (* Part[x, 1]=x[[1]]... *)
(*nested[CompoundExpression[a__]]:=Module[{$list},
  myGrid[Riffle[
  Thread[{, nested /@ Hold[a] // Apply@List}],
  $list] /. $list -> {, ";"}]
];*)
nested[(h : Block | Module)[v_, a_]] := 
  myGrid[{ (* 1st arg List[x,y]={x,y} *)
    {Row[{h, "["}], SpanFromLeft},
    {, myGrid@{{HoldForm[v]}}},
    {, nested[a]},
    {"]"}}];
nested[(h : Set | SetDelayed)[v_, a_]] := 
  myGrid[{ (* v=... or v:=... *)
    {HoldForm[h[v, ""]], SpanFromLeft},
    {, nested[a]}}];

(* Main definitions *)
nested[h_[a___]] := myGrid[{
    {Row[{h, "["}], SpanFromLeft},
    Sequence @@ Thread[{, nested /@ Hold[a] // Apply@List}],
    {"]"}}];
nested[x_] := myGrid@{{HoldForm[x]}};
```

Each argument is spanned by a pink divider:

```
nested[
 Select[Flatten[Module[{x}, x = #;
      Join[x[[1]], #] & /@ x[[2 ;; -1]]] & /@ igraph, 1], 
  Length@# > 1 &]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Appendix: ...in a simpler way**

It occurred to me that the OP wants the code refactored, which I missed at first.

The most egregious obfuscation is the use of `Module` to localize the argument `#1`.  It seems the author was not familiar with `Function[{x}, body]`.  One can simply change `Module` to `Function` and get rid of the `x = #;` and the trailing `&`, preferably adding a comment:

```
Block[{igraph =
  {{{1, 11}, {2}, {3}}, {{4}, {5, 10}, {6}}, {{7}, {8}, {}}}},
 
 Select[
  Flatten[
   Function[{x}, (* join First list in x to Rest of lists in x *)
     Join[First[x], #] & /@ Rest[x]
     ] /@ igraph, (* for each list in igraph *)
   1],
  Length@# > 1 &]
 
 ]

(*  {{1, 11, 2}, {1, 11, 3}, {4, 5, 10}, {4, 6}, {7, 8}}  *)
```

Alternatively, one could name the function and take advantage of Mathematica's pattern-matching and term-rewriting capabilities:

```
joinFirstToRest[{x1_, x2___}] := Join[x1, #] & /@ {x2}; 

Block[{igraph =
  {{{1, 11}, {2}, {3}}, {{4}, {5, 10}, {6}}, {{7}, {8}, {}}}},
 
 Select[
  Flatten[joinFirstToRest /@ igraph, 1],
  Length[#] > 1 &]
 
 ]
```

If one is looking for a procedural equivalent to `joinFirstToRest /@ igraph`, which is the same as `Map[joinFirstToRest, igraph]` ("I am struggling to write the code without these"), I offer this for educational purposes:

```
Table[joinFirstToRest[x], {x, igraph}]
```

(Change `Map` to `Table`, pick an iterator `x` and plug it into the function and the list-iterator form for `Table`.)  The expression inside the OP's `Flatten[expr, 1]` becomes, after simplifying `Function[{x}, body][x]` to just `body`, the following:

```
Table[Join[x[[1]], #] & /@ x[[2 ;; -1]]], {x, igraph}]
```

or, transforming `Map` again,

```
Table[
 Table[Join[x[[1]], y], {y, x[[2 ;; -1]]}],
 {x, igraph}]
```

which could be combined into

```
Table[Join[First@x, y], {x, igraph}, {y, Rest@x}]
```

The 2D `Table` form also reveals why the next step might be to `Flatten` it one level.  I usually like `Map` better than `Table`, but `Table` seems easier to read here. I still prefer `First@x` to `First[x]` and certainly `Rest@x` to `x[[2 ;; -1]]`, especially when they are themselves adjacent to brackets and braces.